# Mapping in .Net

Tags: .net, mapping, automapper

I work with application that requires writing a converter data type to another. For example:

```
public class WcfContactName
{
public string FirstName {get; set;}
public string LastName {get; set;}
}
public class IosContactName
{
public string FirstName {get; set;}
public string LastName {get; set;}
}
```

I have to write a utilitarian class (AutoMapper), which automatically performs mapping Property class provided that:
- Have the same name (ignore the lower / upper case)
- Have the same data type
 
I have to make a mapping Property for unlimited nesting level. You also need to allow certain Property ignored during conversion. When writing code follow the Test-driven development process. Who can help me? thank's

Comment: Do you have any specific problems? This is way too broad. You're actually asking others to write your mapper.

Comment: You tagged your post `Automapper`. That is an open source project that already does what you've outlined.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Reflection` (`System.Reflection` namespace) mechanism. For the two mapped types you need to get information about the types (`TypeInfo` class), and their properties (`PropertyInfo` class), and then build the logic for your mapping. With the usage of `PropertyInfo` class you can get names, and types of properties. `Reflection` allows you to get and set values of properties of objects so you will be able to build your mapper. It also allows you to call methods, constructors, and to do other manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

You could use my AutoMapper project and not go through the trouble of writing your own.

http://automapper.org

https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AutoMap
    {
        public List<string> BlackList = new List<string>();

        //public void Map(object o1, object o2)        
        public void Map<K, T>(K o1, T o2)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < BlackList.Count; i++)
            {
                BlackList[i] = BlackList[i].ToUpper();
            }
            //BlackList.ForEach(delegate(string s) { s = s.ToUpper(); });

            //if (o1 == null || o2 == null)
            //    return;                     

            //Type t1 = o1.GetType();
            Type t1 = typeof(K);
            IList<PropertyInfo> props1 = new List<PropertyInfo>(t1.GetProperties());

            //Type t2 = o2.GetType();
            Type t2 = typeof(T);
            IList<PropertyInfo> props2 = new List<PropertyInfo>(t2.GetProperties());            

            for (int i = 0; i < props1.Count; i++)
            {
                object propValue1 = (o1 != null ? props1[i].GetValue(o1, null) : null);

                string Name = props1[i].Name;
                Type tt1 = props1[i].PropertyType;

                for (int j = 0; j < props2.Count; j++)
                {

                    if (!BlackList.Contains(props2[j].Name.ToUpper()) 
                        && props2[j].Name.ToUpper() == Name.ToUpper())
                    {
                        object propValue2 = (o2 != null ? props2[j].GetValue(o2, null) : null);
                        Type tt2 = props2[j].PropertyType;

                        if (tt1.Equals(tt2))
                        {
                            if (o2!= null)
                                props2[j].SetValue(o2, propValue1, null);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (tt1.IsClass && tt2.IsClass)
                            {                                                                                      

                                MethodInfo mi = this.GetType().GetMethod("Map").MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { tt1, tt2 });
                                mi.Invoke(this, new object[] { propValue1, propValue2 });

                                props2[j].SetValue(o2, propValue2, null);
                            }
                        }


                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }


    }
```